# Act of Ending Friendship

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the best word for a situation when two friend end their friendship because of a dispute? (Verb, Noun,...)
I couldn't find anything online about friendship, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: One common context is two friends who have a *sexual* relationship (often, *married*). If they ***fall out*** (have a serious dispute), and go their separate ways, each is the ***estranged*** husband / wife / partner of the other. I can't think of a single word to fit *Jack and Jill [verbed]* - ***split up*** is common, but that invariably implies they were previously sexual / romantic partners, not just "friends".

Comment: He unfriended me!

Comment: They had a falling out.

Answer (score 2):

English doesn't have a common word or term for a friendship breaking up, like it does for a romantic relationship breaking up (eg. divorce, break up, split up, separate).

A **fall out** is the noun that most commonly comes to mind.

> [***fall out***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fall-out) *noun* to have an ​argument or ​disagreement that ​ends a ​relationship:
>
> *Joan and I had a fall out over money and we're no longer friends.*

You can use **fell out** as a verb.

> Joan and I fell out over money and we're no longer friends.

You could simply say **stopped being friends**.

> Joan and I had a dispute about money and we're no longer friends.
>
> Joan and I had a dispute about money and we're no longer on speaking terms.
>
> Joan and I had a dispute about money and we've stopped being friends.

Comment: I've not heard _a fall-out_ used as a noun like that.  _A falling out_, yes.

Comment: @James - As an Englishman (that sounds so pretentious, but anyway) I've heard it used that way.

Comment: The dictionary link to "fall out" is only showing me verbs.  And although you have the word "noun", the definition you give is for a verb, and the example doesn't match.

Comment: @James: I upvoted your comment because [***falling out***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+had+a+falling+out%22) is far more common (with over 10K hits in Google Books there). But both [*they had a **fall-out***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+had+a+fall+out%22) and the one-word [***...fallout***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+had+a+fallout%22) produce hundreds of hits, and with a usage like this I don't think you can appeal to dictionaries to rule any particular variants out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm just pointing out that the [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fall-out) provided doesn't list a noun definition.  Also the books listed in [...fallout](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+had+a+fallout%22) either are followed with "shelter" or don't actually contain the word (this is strange to me, why are they in results)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the word "**rupture**", a breach of harmonious, friendly, or peaceful relations. It applies for both friendship and love.

*Example: The rupture with Johnson was painful, but she came to see it as a liberation*.

Answer (score 1):

Alienated, disaffected, estranged, former, antecedent, erstwhile, deposed, heretofore, and ci-devant come to mind.

- Alienated: Cause (someone) to feel isolated or estranged, or to become unsympathetic or hostile
- Disaffected: Dissatisfied with the people in authority and no longer willing to support them
- Estranged: (Of a person) no longer close or affectionate to someone
- Former: Having previously filled a particular role or been a particular thing
- Antecedent: Preceding in time or order; previous or preexisting
- Erstwhile: former; that until recently was the type of person or thing described but is not any more
- Deposed: Removed from office or from power suddenly and forcefully
- Heretofore: Before now
- Ci-devant: From or in an earlier time (used to indicate that someone or something once possessed a specified characteristic but no longer does so); Origin...Early 18th century: French, literally 'heretofore'.

Per OED

Comment: Hi Katherine! These are all good words, but you should spend some time to add definitions for most - if not all - of your suggestions. That's what makes a helpful and useful answer, and your answer will be more likely to be accepted.

Comment: @DogLover ... Thanks, I will include that in later posts.  I cut my teeth on the unabridged dictionary.  Anytime I asked how to spell or what does a word mean, I got the same answer ... "look it up!"  Needless to say, I have read that enormous tome cover to cover.  Sorry, old habits die hard.  At least I spelled them for the questioner.

Comment: Could you pick one word to suggest to the op, and not give 9, hoping one sticks?  This is a sort of shotgun answer.

Comment: @michael_timofeev I could pick one word for myself.  The questioner seemed to be asking for options.  Since there is no definitive word for this particular situation, and our language is full of possibilities, I didn't want to presume intimate understanding of the questioner's intent.  So, I tried to present some possible options.  I am so sorry if you think this is a "shotgun" answer, but as a long-time practitioner of the art of teaching people to think, I have found that having options encourages self determination.

Comment: @michael_timofeev  To presume that an immature perspective is incapable of growth is disrespectful.  To take the easy route by selecting the "right" answer is teaching memorization, not thinking.

Comment: @Katherine ah...a blanket statement about me and the students I have.